# How to work with lookup data using RtkQuery

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

In my database I have some lookup tables that are used in Select Items. I am trying to load all those tables data when the app loads in a single slice. I created a sql query in the backend to return all those data in a single JSON object.

```
{
"custTypes": [
    {
        "code": 1,
        "name": "افراد"
    },
    {
        "code": 2,
        "name": "شركات"
    },
    {
        "code": 3,
        "name": "ccc"
    }
],
"nationalities": [
    {
        "code": 3,
        "name": "السعوديه"
    },
    {
        "code": 4,
        "name": "تركيا"
    },
    {
        "code": 5,
        "name": "الاردن"
    },
    {
        "code": 6,
        "name": "ليتوانيا"
    },
    {
        "code": 7,
        "name": "الصين"
    }
 ]
}
```

Then I created an API slice to fetch the data:

```
import { createEntityAdapter, createSelector } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { apiSlice } from "../../App/api/apiSlice";

const custLookupsAdapter = createEntityAdapter();
const initialState = custLookupsAdapter.getInitialState();

export const customerLookupsApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getCustomerLookups: builder.query({
      query: () => "/sales/customerlookups",
      transformResponse: (res) => {
        return custLookupsAdapter.setAll(initialState, res);
      },
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetCustomerLookupsQuery } = customerLookupsApiSlice;

export const selectCustomerLookupResult =
  customerLookupsApiSlice.endpoints.getCustomerLookups.select();

export const selectCustomerLookupData = createSelector(
  selectCustomerLookupResult,
  (customerLookup) => customerLookup.data
);

export const { selectAll: selectAllCustomerLookups } =
  custLookupsAdapter.getSelectors(
    (state) => selectCustomerLookupData(state) ?? initialState
  );
```

Now the problem is not all the data are stored in redux. When I explore the store in Redux chrome extension I find the only the first array are stored. The array with the key "custTypes"
[image]

So how can I fix this so that I could get and work with the entire JSON object?

Comment: For the data you have I don't think using the `createEntityAdapter` is the correct tool for the job. From what I can tell you should return the fetched JSON response, no need to transform it.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes I tried that but I hade issue with the last export in the code above. I am using custLookupsAdapter.getSelectors() to get create selectors. Could you provide an alternative code without using EntityAdapter?

Comment: Why do you need any special entity selectors? If you don't need an entity adapter then you also don't need `custLookupsAdapter.getSelectors`. The query should already cache the result and return the data to the component. Can you [edit] your post to share a [mcve] where you are making this query request and trying to use the fetched JSON data?

Comment: Well I used the adapter because the same use case was done this way in the [docs](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-8-rtk-query-advanced#managing-users-data). Also this data will be used every single form component in the app and what I provided is a very small set of data. I did consider dealing with it like any other endpoint but in most tutorials they did this way using the adapter.

Comment: Sorry I wouldn't be able to reproduce but we can use the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reduxjs/redux-essentials-example-app/tree/checkpoint-6-rtkqConversion/?from-embed) from the docs, my implementation is similar.

Comment: Plus I don't think I can call two apiSlice hooks in the same component. Because with the way you suggesting, In every component I would have the hook to fetch the form data and another hook to fetch the options of the select fields.

Comment: The entity adaptor is for normalized data. Your data doesn't appear to be normalized or normalizable. You can call as many React hooks in a component as it necessary to do whatever it is they do. Have you ***tried*** just not transforming the response and let RTKQ cache the fetched result, and accessing that in the UI with the `useGetCustomerLookupsQuery` hook?

Answer (score 0):

As @Drew Reese mentioned in one of the comments, I should use the normal `useGetCustomerLookupsQuery` hook. But on top of that, to only select the data I need from the returned data, I found the `selectFromResult` attribute in the [redux transformation docs](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-8-rtk-query-advanced#comparing-transformation-approaches).

I removed the adapter and selector code from the `customerLookupsApiSlice`:

```
import { createEntityAdapter, createSelector } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { apiSlice } from "../../App/api/apiSlice";

export const customerLookupsApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getCustomerLookups: builder.query({
      query: () => "/sales/customerlookups",
      // transformResponse: (res) => {
      //   return custLookupsAdapter.setAll(initialState, res);
      // },
    }),
  }),
});
export const { useGetCustomerLookupsQuery } = customerLookupsApiSlice;
```

Then in the UI I used the `selectFromResult` while calling the hook:

```
const { custTypes, nationalities, governorates, goverSection } =
    useGetCustomerLookupsQuery(undefined, {
      selectFromResult: (x) => ({
        custTypes: x.data.custTypes,
        nationalities: x.data.nationalities,
        governorates: x.data.governorates,
        goverSection: x.data.goverSection,
      }),
    });
```